# MySQL - how to GROUP BY a column that has conditions

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I've tried searching for this, but can't find anything similar.  Most questions are about using conditionals in group by statements.

I have a table with columns 'subject' and 'content'.  I want to count the instances of bank names in 'content'.

If I do the following, I get what I expect: a row for each record, some are "BofA", some are "USAA", most are "Other".

```
select
case
    when content like '%bank of america%' then "BofA"
    when content like '%usaa%' then "USAA"
    else "Other"
end as 'FI'
from topics
```

Result is something like:

```
FI
Other
Other
BofA
Other
Other
USAA
Other
...
```

Ok, fine.  But if I try to do a count() and group by FI:

```
select
case
    when content like '%bank of america%' then "BofA"
    when content like '%usaa%' then "USAA"
    else "Other"
end as 'FI',
count(*)

from topics

group by 'FI'
```

Result:

```
FI      | count(*)
Other   | 43203
```

What I want is something like this:

```
FI      | count(*)
BofA    | 1298
USAA    | 701
Other   | 41134
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I know I could probably do this a few different ways, but it seems like this should be working...  I'm open to other methods as well.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it should work.  However, you could try this:

```
select fi,count(*) from 
(
  select
  case
    when content like '%bank of america%' then "BofA"
    when content like '%usaa%' then "USAA"
    else "Other"
  end as fi
  from topics
)
group by fi
```

Comment: don't you need a table alias? ie ...from topics) **x** group by fi

Comment: Thanks, that did work. although I had to give the table an alias.